# Function Usage for a Module in Python

Tags: python

Am learning python and got struck with some question
 When we import the module as whole (*) or some needed functions, how to see the usage of those functions 
Ex:

```
import math

dir(math)

['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan', 'atan2', 'atanh', 'ceil', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'erf', 'erfc', 'exp', 'expm1', 'fabs', 'factorial', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum', 'gamma', 'gcd', 'hypot', 'inf', 'isclose', 'isfinite', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'ldexp', 'lgamma', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p', 'log2', 'modf', 'nan', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'remainder', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'tau', 'trunc']
```

I have lot of functions from the math module but how to use them will they take 1 arg or more than that or how to use.
ex: how to use `cos` or how to use `floor` etc

I can get the usage of module math but need the functions inside the module usage.

mentioned above

```
import math

dir(math)

['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan', 'atan2', 'atanh', 'ceil', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'erf', 'erfc', 'exp', 'expm1', 'fabs', 'factorial', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum', 'gamma', 'gcd', 'hypot', 'inf', 'isclose', 'isfinite', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'ldexp', 'lgamma', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p', 'log2', 'modf', 'nan', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'remainder', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'tau', 'trunc']
```

Like the dir() looking for something to see how to use each function inside the module.

Currently I use python 2.6 and python 3.5 on MAC

Comment: Have your tried `help`? Like `help(math.cos)`

Answer (score 0):

you could just RTFM https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/math.html ... it would be the best way

Answer (score 0):

Try ipython, just type func? or func??